# Generate A treeview with a list of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

The two classes I am using are as follows

```
public class FoundDirectory 
{
     public string fullPath { get; set; }
     public string parent { get; set; }
     public string directoryName { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<FoundDirectory> subDirectories { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<FoundFile> subFiles { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return directoryName;
     }
}

public class FoundFile 
{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string fullPath { get; set; }

    public long fileLength { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

I am trying to generate a TreeView from a recursive hard drive scan. I pass in an ObservableCollection to the TreeView. I can get it to display the subdirectories nested correctly but can not get it to display the sub files at all. My XAML is as follows:

```
    <TreeView Name="directoryTree" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=sortedDirList}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=subDirectories}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=directoryName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

I have tried multiple different ways to display the subfiles but nothing seems to work

Comment: I would suggest treating it like a tree, so files/directories are just nodes with a single list of children(files and directories) and the only difference is that the file nodes wont have any children. That should display everything

Comment: Ok so how would that look in the XAML?

Comment: not much changes, subDirectories becomes children (or whatever you name the list) in the binding, and that should work

Comment: if you want files and directories to display differently, you would want a list of some interface they both implement, and then you can create a datatemplate for each type and they will automatically use the correct template

Comment: I want the files to be nested under the directory they belong to. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is a file explorer

Comment: This seems like the hard way to do it, No? I would create a collection of objects "Nodes" and as you hit a parent that'd be a directory, iterating through .anything would be files... What you're attempting to do is connect them which would require two iterations or an index to place them which is a waste. Might as well do it as you're building the directory collection.

Comment: @jsomers89 If both files and directories are in the parents list then they will both be displayed in the directory they belong to, I just mentioned templating in case that interested you or was a requirement you hadn't mentioned

Comment: @user2455627 both the files and directories are in a parent object but in seperate list. Each directory has a list of files and a list of  sub directories

Comment: @jsomers89 right, but I'm suggesting make a single list with both, how you do this is up to you (i.e. interface, new class, etc..) and that both files and directories have the list, but files' list is empty, whereas directories have stuff in the lists

Comment: @jsomers89 another solution is to add a ListBox inside the hierarchical data template that binds to the file list

Comment: @user2455627 thanks will work away at one of those solutions

Comment: @user2455627 been trying for several more hours seems like a new class is going to be the way to go cant seem to wrap my head around how the new class should look

Comment: @jsomers89 I added an answer with an example of how you could go about making the class, let me know if you still have any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could go about this:

```
public class Node
{
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Size {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Children {get; set;}

    public string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<TreeView Name="directoryTree" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=sortedDirList}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Then just make sortedDirList a list containing just the root directory, and that should expand out properly.

Note: The class/variable names are simply placeholders, feel free to rename them.

To recursively populate the tree write something like this should work:

```
public void DirectorySearch(Node node)
{
    foreach(string f in Directory.GetFiles(node.Name))
    {
        //initialize a node with the file info
        node.Children.Add(fileNode);
    }
    foreach(var d in Directory.GetDirectories(node.Name)
    {
        //initialize a node with directory info
        node.Children.Add(dirNode);
        DirectorySearch(dirNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: here is my search function where do I use that class. I think this is really where I have been getting confused                                                                                   public void directorySearch2(string directoryToSearch)
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(directoryToSearch))
                {
                    
                }

                foreach (var d in Directory.GetDirectories(directoryToSearch))
                {
                    
                    directorySearch(d);
                }
            }           
        }